# How to get date and amount between two columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I stuck in a query and table is

```
TP_DEALNUM  DEALDATE    MATURITYDATE    TP_DEALTYPE     TP_NETVALUE
500         20180521    20180524        NBORR           209221500
501         20180525    20180527        NBORR           249221500
502         20180527    20180527        NBORR           747664500
601         20180530    20180531        CBORR           1000000000
602         20180530    20180531        CBORR           500000000
```

and my query is,
 if date difference between dealdate and MATURITYDATE is =2 then I need

```
DEALDATE  TP_NETVALUE
20180525   249221500
20180526   249221500
```

and  if date difference between dealdate and MATURITYDATE is =3 then I need

```
DEALDATE  TP_NETVALUE
20180521   209221500
20180522   209221500
20180523   209221500
```

and date difference  will be increasing till 14

I tried below query,But I'm not getting output

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tp_dealnum,dealdate,  maturitydate,TP_DEALTYPE,TP_NETVALUE, 
    (maturitydate -dealdate) AS DateDiff
    FROM tablename)
    SELECT case WHEN datediff=2 THEN dealdate+1 
            WHEN datediff=3 THEN dealdate+1 END AS dealdate_1,
    tp_netvalue  FROM cte 
    WHERE  DateDiff >= 2
```

Comment: . . What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: oracle 11g version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a calendar table approach here.  Maintain a record of all deal dates which would cover the gaps in your current table, and then join to it:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT date '2018-05-01' AS DEALDATE FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-05-02' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-05-02' FROM dual UNION ALL
    ....
    SELECT date '2018-05-30' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-05-31' FROM dual
)

SELECT
    d.DEALDATE,
    t.TP_NETVALUE
FROM dates d
INNER JOIN tablename t
    ON d.DEALDATE BETWEEN t.DEALDATE AND t.MATURITYDATE - 1
WHERE
    t.MATURITYDATE - t.DEALDATE BETWEEN 2 AND 3;
```

Note that this just generates the missing data.  If you wanted to incorporate it into some other query/logic, then you would have to do additional work.

Answer (score 0):

The key is generating another CTE with intermittent dates like this-

```
WITH deal AS
         (SELECT 500 TP_DEALNUM,
                 20180521 DEALDATE,
                 20180524 MATURITYDATE,
                 'NBORR' TP_DEALTYPE,
                 209221500 TP_NETVALUE
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 501, 20180525, 20180527, 'NBORR', 249221500 FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 502, 20180527, 20180527, 'NBORR', 747664500 FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 601, 20180530, 20180531, 'CBORR', 1000000000 FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 602, 20180530, 20180531, 'CBORR', 500000000 FROM dual),
     daterange AS
         (SELECT min (dealdate) start_date, max (maturitydate) end_date
            FROM deal),
     intermittent_date AS
         (    SELECT start_date + level - 1 AS int_date
                FROM daterange
          CONNECT BY start_date + level - 1 <= end_date)
SELECT id.int_date dealdate, dl.tp_netvalue
  FROM deal dl
       INNER JOIN intermittent_date id
           ON id.int_date BETWEEN dl.dealdate AND dl.maturitydate - 1
 WHERE dl.maturitydate - dl.dealdate = 2;
```

Output:

```
  DEALDATE TP_NETVALUE
---------- -----------
  20180525   249221500
  20180526   249221500
```